# How to create slanted edges and rounded handles for a tray?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I'm trying to create this item:

[image]

I'm stuck on how to slant the edges up and to make handles. Can someone give me advice ?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I'd do it using a *Mirror Modifier* and a *Solidify Modifier*.

1. Create a quarter of the tray, with no thickness.
2. Add a *Mirror Modifier* and a *Solidify Modifier*
3. Tilt the handle using a 3D cursor as pivot (or proportional editing)
4. Tilt the sides just by moving upper vertices.

*The solidify modifier keeps even thicknes for you, saving fiddling with vertices.*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Model the base of your box.
2. Select this edges of the corner and use the shear tool and use 0.5
   or -0.5 depending in the side, you can use any value you want.
3. Repeat the earlier step to the another corner edges, and done!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]